# Convert date to timestamp javascript

Tags: javascript

I have got a date in this format: **Tuesday, 31st October 2017** and tried to convert it with **new Date();** but it didn't work.

Is there any simple way how to convert this date into a timestamp? I am not a developer but need quickly achieve this small task.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to do this as a one-off (not being a developer and all)…? Or you need to write something which will automatically convert dates in such a format?

Comment: if you remove number suffix first, standard method seems working:
new Date("Tuesday, 31 October 2017");

Comment: It works only if Day hasn't got st, th or nd, but with those suffixes it gives and error Invalid Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @serjeii mentioned in the comment you can just get rid of the strings next to the day indicating which n-th day of the month you have there.

Here is a nice 1 liner solution for you:

```
Date("Tuesday, 31st October 2017".replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/, "$1"));
```

Of course, you can declare your date as a variable and then call the replace function.

```
var my_date = "Tuesday, 31st October 2017";
Date(my_date.replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/, "$1"));
```

You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?  The last line will print out the timestamp.  Since your date is not in a standard format, I parsed the string and built it in the correct format for `Date.parse()` to work.

```
var dateStr = "Tuesday, 31st October 2017";
dateStr = dateStr.replace(/.*, /, ''); //Remove leading weekday name
var arr = dateStr.split(' '); //Split into 3 parts
var dateNum = arr[0].replace(/st|nd|rd/, ''); //Strip non digits from day 
var finalDateStr = arr[1] + ' ' + dateNum + ' ' + arr[2];
var dt = Date.parse(finalDateStr);
console.log(dt); //timestamp
```